# Storing values in array of object, but in 2 methods Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
myAccount[0] = new Calculations(firstName, lastName, pin);

myAccount[0] = new Calculations(totalBalance);
```

Hello! I've been practicing with array of objects, but I ran into a problem. I have 2 classes (Drive and Calculations). Both above lines of code are in the drive class, but in 2 different methods. In the first method I have the first line of code, and in the second method I have the second line of code. I'm trying to store all 4 in the first index, but I guess totalBalance overwrites the firstName, lastName, and pin which I suppose makes sense. So I guess the question is how do I store multiple values in the first object if I need to use separate methods? Also in case you're wondering why I don't just do it all in one method, it's because I want to display just the firstName, lastName, and pin in one panel, and then all 4 in another panel(firstName, lastName, and pin display null while totalBalance displays the the correct output which is why I figure the second line of code overwrites the first). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should still instantiate a `Calculations` object with all 4 parameters and just have two different display methods:

> 1. One display method that displays just the firstName, secondName, and pin
> 2. One display method that displays all 4 fields.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Calculations[] myAccounts = new Calculations[5];

    myAccounts[0] = new Calculations("John", "Doe", 1234, 100.00);
    System.out.println("Summary");
    System.out.println(myAccounts[0].DisplaySummary());

    System.out.println("Full Info");
    System.out.println(myAccounts[0].DisplayFull());   
}

public static class Calculations {
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    int pin = 0;
    double totalBalance = 0;
    DecimalFormat formatter;

    public Calculations(String fn, String ln, int p, double tb) {
        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
        pin = p;
        totalBalance = tb;

        formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
    }

    public String DisplaySummary() {
        return String.format("First Name: %s\r\nLast Name: %s\r\nPin: %d\r\n", firstName, lastName, pin);
    }

    public String DisplayFull() {
        return DisplaySummary() + "Total Balance: $" + formatter.format(totalBalance);
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create **setter** and **getter** methods, that way you can safely set values properly.

Example:

```
public class Calculations {
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    int pin = 0;
    int totalBalance = 0;

    public Calculations(String fn, String ln, int p) {
         firstName = fn;
         lastName = ln;
         pin = p;
    }

    public void setTotalBalance(int total) {
         totalBalance = total;
    }

    public int getTotalBalance() {
         return totalBalance;
    }
}
```

After that you can just do:

```
myAccount[0] = new Calculations(firstName, lastName, pin);

myAccount[0].setTotalBalance(totalBalance);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To store multiple values in the first index or any index in an array you can have a multiple dimensional array.  For example

```
myAccount[0][0] = new Calculations(firstName, lastName, pin);

myAccount[0][1] = new Calculations(totalBalance);
```

This would be initialized as `Calculations myAccount[][] = new Calculations[amount][2];`